# Javascript/CSS/HTML5 - Get Default Application Icon

Tags: javascript, html, icons, web

Is there any possible way to get the icon for the default application that would open a file or mime type in javascript/css/html5? It only has to work on chrome, so cross-browser compatibility isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot mess outside the browser window for security reasons. You could use some generic icons if you want.

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought, just figured I'd check anyway...thanks!

Comment: Please select the tick in the left of the answer if it helped you as of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts) privilege indicates.

Comment: I will in about 5-10 min, I just want to see if anybody else has some hack-ish solution that might work (this is most likely only going to have to run on my computers, so I can change security policies if needed)

Comment: Heh, I just tried to, and it tells me I have to wait another 4 minutes anyway :P